# Flood fill path in C

Tags: c, flood-fill

I want to create a program where if I input

for example:

```
5
###O#
#OOO#
##O##
#OO##
##O##
```

5 is the size of the maze.

output: yes
, because there is a path to cross the maze

if the input is

```
5
###O#
#OOO#
#####
#OO##
##O##
```

the output will be no, because the path is blocked.

this is my current code,, it's not working properly

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define MAX 1001

char maze[MAX][MAX];
bool passed[MAX][MAX];

void move(int y, int x, int size)
{
    if (maze[y][x] == '#' || passed[y][x] == true || y < 0 || x < 0 || y >= size || x >= size) return;

    passed[y][x] = true;
    move(y + 1, x, length, width);
    move(y - 1, x, length, width);
    move(y, x + 1, length, width);
    move(y, x - 1, length, width);
}

int main()
{
    int size;
    scanf("%d", &size);
    int y, x;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
        {
            scanf(" %c", &maze[i][j]);
            if (maze[i][j] == 'O')
            {
                y = i;
                x = j;
            }
        }
    }

    move(y, x, size);
    if (passed[size- 1][size- 1])
    {
        printf("Yes\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("No\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: One problem is that you access `maze[y][x]` and `passed[y][x]` before checking that `y` and `x` are in range.

Comment: `passed[size- 1][size- 1]` only checks one tile in the last row.

Comment: The recursive calls to `move` have more arguments than declared.